# Creating mysql view with function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created this below function to use this in mysql view. but when I run the view query its showing error "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation
". but I altered function varchar to int. it's working fine. Please help me out

```
CREATE FUNCTION `book_subject`() RETURNS varchar(10) CHARSET utf8
RETURN @subject

CREATE 
VIEW `qry_tools` AS
SELECT 
    `companyID`.`companyID` AS `companyID`
FROM companymaster
WHERE
    ((`motmaster`.`companyID` = BOOK_SUBJECT()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table might have latin1_swedish_ci collation,

If you create a stored function returning a UTF8 string, there is no simple way of telling that latin1_swedish_ci strings should be returned and used in further expressions calling the function

**Documentation says that the default collation for returned string is used (which is UTF8_GENERAL_CI in case of UTF8 character set).**

However if you want your string expressions (calling your function) to use latin1_swedish_ci you have to mention "collate latin1_swedish_ci" in all terms of the expression.

```
 RETURN @subject collate latin1_swedish_ci
```

for more

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24690

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `book_subject`() RETURNS varchar(10) CHARSET utf8
RETURN @subject

CREATE 
VIEW `qry_tools` AS
SELECT 
    `companyID`.`companyID` AS `companyID`
FROM companymaster
WHERE
    ((`motmaster`.`companyID` collate latin1_swedish_ci = BOOK_SUBJECT() collate latin1_swedish_ci))
```

You should use the same collation to compare. It would be work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers but neither of the code worked. i found the solution after looking at the reply.

```
  (CONVERT( `motmaster`.`companyID` USING UTF8) = BOOK_SUBJECT())
```